# Cant type in text fields Vaadin

Tags: java, spring, vaadin

I can't input anything to my text fields in Vaadin.
They seems like they are readOnly but I change it to false and not helping.
I'm adding links to CarForm where I create form of my fields and CarView where I implement the CarFrom.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0nmwh.png)

https://github.com/pietryczko/Car-Rental-Frontend/commit/b1402d31970925c405b1ba4e1cd29c4dc70447b9#diff-d81d9d922d1c41ff4195d75d75ab037132f09673855aad9de429028c39ead13a

https://github.com/pietryczko/Car-Rental-Frontend/comamit/b1402d31970925c405b1ba4e1cd29c4dc70447b9#diff-4fffa8de6937448a38eeee4881c32009b3b6923be141ededfc5ef585d50497a1

Comment: Many links are shared, provide more details about them as well, and share code that you've done so far

Answer (score 3):

It seems like that the Dto class you are using with Binder has no setter methods, thus binder marks the UI fields as readonly

Comment: I added setters and works! thank you very much for your help :)